# error : No implementation found for void org.webrtc.PeerConnectionFactory.initializeFieldTrials

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webrtc

I am making video and voice call application using playRTC of webRTC. I am currently experiencing this error. The AVD, i am using is Nexus 5 api 28. Please provide a solution.

error code.

```
E/.playrtc.sampl: No implementation found for void org.webrtc.PeerConnectionFactory.initializeFieldTrials(java.lang.String) (tried Java_org_webrtc_PeerConnectionFactory_initializeFieldTrials and Java_org_webrtc_PeerConnectionFactory_initializeFieldTrials__Ljava_lang_String_2)
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.playrtc.sample, PID: 3045
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for void org.webrtc.PeerConnectionFactory.initializeFieldTrials(java.lang.String) (tried Java_org_webrtc_PeerConnectionFactory_initializeFieldTrials and Java_org_webrtc_PeerConnectionFactory_initializeFieldTrials__Ljava_lang_String_2)
    at org.webrtc.PeerConnectionFactory.initializeFieldTrials(Native Method)
    at com.sktelecom.playrtc.webrtc.a.a(Unknown Source:62)
    at com.sktelecom.playrtc.c.a(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.sktelecom.playrtc.PlayRTCImpl.<init>(Unknown Source:157)
    at com.sktelecom.playrtc.PlayRTCImpl.a(Unknown Source:2)
    at com.sktelecom.playrtc.PlayRTCFactory.createPlayRTC(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.playrtc.sample.handler.PlayRTCHandler.createPlayRTC(PlayRTCHandler.java:242)
    at com.playrtc.sample.PlayRTCActivity.onCreate(PlayRTCActivity.java:172)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 3045 SIG: 9
Application terminated.
```

my build:gradle(module:app) is

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.playrtc.sample"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 15
    versionName "2.3.3"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
splits {
    abi {
        enable true
        reset()
        include 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'mips', 'mips64', 'arm64-v8a'
        universalApk false
    }
}
}
```

how to solve this error ?

Comment: If you still need this functionality, I think there is a detail for everything, you're looking for:[Android_Realtime_Communication_Using_WebRTC](https://github.com/mail2chromium/Android_Realtime_Communication_Using_WebRTC)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following method:

```java
val options = PeerConnectionFactory.InitializationOptions.builder(context)
    .setFieldTrials("WebRTC-H264HighProfile/Enabled/")

PeerConnectionFactory.initialize(options);
```

`initializeFieldTrials` is [deprecated](https://twilio.github.io/twilio-video-android/docs/6.0.0-beta2/tvi/webrtc/PeerConnectionFactory.html#initializeFieldTrials-java.lang.String-)